# React three fiber and react-router-dom. Error: cannot use <Link> outside of <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-v4, react-three-fiber

So I was told that you cannot use react-router-dom with react-three-fiber due to some technical issues since react-router isn't able to access the provider inside canvas. Well I tried to put a `Link` tag outside my canvas and it does redirect when elements are clicked to another page but obviously this applies to all elements rather than a specific one which is what I want. I have seen examples of using portals or forwarding canvases but i'm afraid this is really confusing for me and I don't know how to apply it.

I was wondering if this could be possible by passing props. For example instead of using `<Link to = "/Page2">` it would be `<Link to = "{link}">` and then I would define link within the component. e.g. `<Cube link = "/Page2">`. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
export default function Page1({ link }) {

  return (
    <>

 <Link to = "/page2">
      <Canvas>

        <ambientLight />
        <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />

        <Suspense fallback={<Fallback />}>

          <Cube position={[-1.2, 0, 0]} time={1000} link="/Page2" />

        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

Thing is when I applied this, nothing happens and I don't know why, is my syntax wrong?
Here is my main [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-microservice-y6qcf?file=/src/page/page1/page1.js) in sandbox. Everything is in Page1.js but it is a little confusing due to the amount it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from the react three fiber spectrum [chat](http://spectrum.chat/react-three-fiber) @mjf had kindly helped me find an answer to this. So @0xca0a said that the issue is the *'context doesn't pierce reconcilers. the  component opens a new render root, that one has no access to the host reconcilers (react-dom) context.'*
So a way around this issue is through bridging react router context into the canvas. First the context is created through the 'history' library from react router dom `import { createBrowserHistory }.

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import App from "./App";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const customHistory = createBrowserHistory({
  // basename: config.urlBasename || ""
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={customHistory}>
    <Route
      component={({ history }) => {
        window.appHistory = history;
        return <App />;
      }}
    />
  </Router>,
  rootElement
);
```

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "react-three-fiber";
import Cube from "./cube";

export default function Page1() {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <ambientLight />
      <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Cube
          position={[-1.2, 0, 0]}
          onClick={() => window.appHistory.push("/page2")}
        />
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  );
}
```

Here is @mjf's sandbox for the working code
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-yonath-j9u1m?from-embed